# Prove $(\sqrt{2})^{\sqrt{3}-1} \gt (\sqrt{3})^{\sqrt{2}-1}$.

Tags: calculus

Prove $(\sqrt{2})^{\sqrt{3}-1} \gt (\sqrt{3})^{\sqrt{2}-1}$

It is part of an exercise where I am given $f,g:(1,\infty) \to \mathbb R,\,\,\, f(x)=x-1-x\ln x, \,\,\,g(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x-1}$.

I must use of the information that $f(x) \lt 0$ for any $x \in (1,\infty)$ and that $g(x)$ is decreasing. I banged my head against the wall last night trying to solve it, I couldn't see any connection between these function and the inequality and tried to rewrite the inequality in a lot of different ways with not much success. What am I missing?

Comment: Is there an inequality between f(x) and g(x) that should be proved?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, is this supposed to be a hint? All that is asked in the exercise is $1)$ Prove $f(x) \lt 0$ and $2)$ Prove $g(x)$ is decreasing. Both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are decreasing and $\lt 0 $

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad....i got it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have
$$
\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{3} - 1} > \sqrt{3}^{\sqrt2-1}\\
\ln\left(\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{3} - 1}\right) > \ln\left( \sqrt{3}^{\sqrt2-1}\right)\\
(\sqrt{3} - 1)\ln\sqrt{2} > (\sqrt2-1)\ln\sqrt{3}\\
\frac{\ln\sqrt2}{\sqrt2-1} > \frac{\ln\sqrt3}{\sqrt3-1}\\
g(\sqrt2) > g(\sqrt3)
$$
which, since $g$ is (strictly) decreasing, is indeed true.

Strictly speacing, the logic here flows upwards: You start with the known fact $g(\sqrt2)>g(\sqrt(3)$, and work your way through the steps upwards to conclude with the top inequality. But when trying to work out exactly what steps to do, it is often a lot more productive and easier to see what you have to do if you start with what you want to show and work your way towards something you know.

Comment: I got to this inequality at some point $(\sqrt{3}-1)\ln \sqrt(2) \gt (\sqrt{2}-1)\ln \sqrt(3)$ at some point, but I did not know it can be rewritten like you did the very next step. I was aware we can multiply diagonally when we deal with an inequality/equality with fractions but I did not realize the opposite of that can be done too. Anyway, now that I look back on this exercise, it was a dead giveaway that we need to use of the fact that $g(x)$ is decreasing, thank you very much for your thorough explanation!

Comment: @RaduGabriel Both $\sqrt3-1$ and $\sqrt2-1$ are positive, so you are free to divide by them without messing up the inequality. Divide by them both simultaneously, as I did, or divide by one of them at a time if that's more comfortable, iyou get the same result in the end.

Comment: I understand now, you have no idea how much I appreciate this <3

Comment: Very smart answer to a seemingly complicated problem. +1

Answer (score 5):

The inequality can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{\log\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}-1}>\frac{\log\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-1}
$$
and it's natural to consider the function
$$
g(x)=\frac{\log x}{x-1}
$$
over the interval $(1,\infty)$. Since
$$
g'(x)=\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}\left(\frac{x-1}{x}-\log x\right)=\frac{f(x)}{x(x-1)^2}
$$
where $f(x)=x-1-x\log x$ (defined over $(1,\infty)$ like $g$).

We have
$$
\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=0
$$
and $f'(x)=1-\log x-1=-\log x$, which is negative over $(1,\infty)$. Hence $f$ is decreasing and so everywhere negative. This implies $g$ is decreasing over $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: Why are you on the interval $]0,1[$ ?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Ouch! Misled by the log. Fixed